# Pong project in assembly 8086

Tags: assembly, x86-16, pong

I have a problem in my pong project. I try that when the ball hits the red bat it will randomly bounce back to the other side, but for some reason it does not recognize the red color. I use AH = 0Dh in int = 10h. The part of the check is in the hitcheck proc.

Here's the code. relevant to my question.

```
hitcheck    PROC
;------batt and com check-------
MOV BH, 2H
MOV DX, ballx
MOV CX, bally
SUB CX, 2
MOV AH, 0Dh      
INT 10H

CMP AL, 1
JE hitmovement
CMP AL, 3
JE comhitmovement

MOV BH, 2H
MOV DX, ballx
MOV CX, bally
ADD CX, 2
MOV AH, 0Dh            
INT 10H

CMP AL, 1
JE hitmovement
CMP AL, 3
JE comhitmovement

MOV BH, 2H
MOV DX, ballx
MOV CX, bally
SUB DX, 2
MOV AH, 0Dh      
INT 10H

CMP AL, 1
JE hitmovement
CMP AL, 3
JE comhitmovement

MOV BH, 2H
MOV DX, ballx
MOV CX, bally
ADD DX, 2
MOV AH, 0Dh      
INT 10H

CMP AL, 1
JE hitmovement
CMP AL, 3
JE comhitmovement
```

Comment: That's a lot of code for us to go through, mate.

Comment: You could really do with just posting the part of the code that doesn't work with a simple way of running it.

Comment: Better yet, learn to use a debugger so you can fix your own issues.

Comment: You don't need to read the screen to detect the ball colliding with the paddle. You know where paddle is and you know where the ball is, so you can just compute the fairly simple intersection of the two.

Comment: Are you using any timer to control ball speed? Because I can't see it moving, I only see the screen redrawing once and again (red line, blue line, green rectangle).

Comment: That's awful lot of BIOS pixel plotting for a poor 8086 to do. If that's really your minimum target then you may want to reconsider your approach.

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts.  By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/)). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.

Comment: FYI rule of thumb when writing assembly: one comment per line

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ```
> MOV AL, 13H ;changes the num of pixels to 640X480 with 16 colors
> ```

Here the comment does not match the video mode number. Mode 13h has a resolution of 320x200 with 256 colors.

> ```
> mov base, 0
> printleftbase:
> printpixel 0, base, 2, 2
> INC base
> CMP base, 199
> JNE printleftbase
> ```

> ```
> mov base, 0
> printrightbase:
> printpixel 319, base, 2, 2
> INC base                   
> CMP base, 199
> JNE printrightbase
> ```

If the intent of the previous code is to draw vertical lines running the height of the screen then you need to compare with 200 instead of 199.

> ```
> ;------batt and com check-------
> MOV BH, 2H
> MOV DX, ballx
> MOV CX, bally
> SUB CX, 2
> MOV AH, 0Dh      
> INT 10H
> ```

In all of your ReadPixel calls you erroneously put the X coord in `DX` and the Y coord in `CX`. It's the other way round. Your *printpixel* macro does is OK.

Also you print the pixels for *batt* and *com* on page 1 but you check for collisions on page 2!

Question: Does your video adapter even support multiple pages in mode 13h?